# How to inject MetaMask Provider in Chrome Sandbox Environment?

Tags: metamask, ceramic-tile-engine

I am building a chrome extension on manifest v3, since it doesn't allow unsafe-eval scripts i had to move some of my code into a sandbox environment. The extension relies on web3 libraries and MetaMask as the Provider but i couldn't get the provider into the sandbox.

Is there any workaround for this?